# Spring jdbc - calling oracle function with advanced return type

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Disclaimer: I'm new to the concept of oracle functions :)
Im trying to call an oracle function using SimpleJdbcCall. I have an issue where the return type seems to be undefined so I'm unsure how to define the out parameter.

```sql
create or replace FUNCTION getAccountDetails(
   v_acc_no  IN  NUMBER := NULL)
RETURN tbl_wrap pipelined IS

-------------Variable declaration-------------------------
--To store the search resultset
TYPE ref1 IS REF CURSOR;
cur_1 ref1;
--Object Intialization
out_rec obj_wrap := obj_wrap(null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);

**-- REMOVED SQL TO GET DATA AND HANDLE ERROS ---** 

/*Fetching values into object type columns*/
FETCH cur_1 into out_rec.TRN_REF_NO,
out_rec.AUT_DT ,
out_rec.DBT_CCY_CD ,
out_rec.DBT_GRS_AM,
out_rec.AM_DCM_PLC ,
out_rec.BNC_FRS_LIN_TX,
out_rec.PMT_SRC_CD,
out_rec.customer_no,
out_rec.ACCOUNT_no,
out_rec.HERITAGE;

EXIT WHEN cur_1%NOTFOUND;
PIPE ROW (out_rec);
END LOOP;
```

From other examples I can see a new oracle type created, but no types have been created in my schema, so what type does it end up as?

I've tried the below code, to make it as generic as possible, but I've not had any luck.
Also gone though this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/old-docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/orcl.datatypes.html), but it seems to be outdated now.

```java
SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(spaJdbcTemplate)
                .withFunctionName("getAccountDetails")
                .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("tbl_wrap", OracleTypes.STRUCT))
SqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("v_acc_no", 1234567, Types.NUMERIC)
Object results = call.executeFunction(Object.class, paramMap);
```

Comment: Your function is invalid as: you never open the cursor; you are missing the final `END` statement; you have `END LOOP` without starting a `LOOP`; you code may have other issues as you never close the cursor (you also don't close the cursor on the `NO_DATA_NEEDED` exception); and the `tbl_wrap` and `obj_wrap` types are undefined.

Comment: Usually, if it's only one SQL query it's not efficient to use pipelined function and a procedure with out sys_refcursor is preferred. Thus, in your procedure you would have the parameter p_rc out sys_refcursor, and in the procedure you would open p_rc for select ...

Comment: Sorry I should have been clear that the SQL has been modified. I left out the selects as all it does it fetch the data, plus i dont own the script (Work thing) 
There are multiple selects in the body. Also the script was created 12 years ago and Im not allowed to change it.

Comment: This is a pipelined function. You can only call it using a query along the lines of `SELECT ... FROM TABLE(getAccountDetails(...))`. I doubt you can get a `SimpleJdbcCall` to work with it.

Comment: Hi @LukeWoodward. I have seen similar posts saying the same. Think I will have to go with that solution and map to an object myself.